# Procedure with "bind varibale" does not return the desired result set

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

I have a table with below structure:

```
create table CUST_MODERN_CHANNEL_BRANCH
(
  customer_Num      NUMBER,
  channel_Code  NUMBER(5)
)
```

Some example data :

```
   Customer_Num       Channel_Code
  =============     ==============
       1                 5
       1                 4
       1                 6
       2                 3
       3                 5
```

I wrote a procedure which you can see the code below :

```
create or replace procedure query_test(res          out sys_refcursor,
                                       order_by     number,
                                       customer_num number) is
  qry varchar2(1000) := ' select * from cust_modern_channel_branch ';
begin

  if customer_num is not null then
    qry := qry || ' where customer_num = :cust ';
  end if;

  if order_by is not null then
    qry := qry || ' order by :ord ';
  end if;
    
        --******* Generate Result 

  if customer_num is not null then
    if order_by is not null then
      open res for qry
        using customer_num, order_by;
    else
      open res for qry
        using order_by;
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

I'm using `bind variable` in my procedure to protect it from injection and make it better in terms of performance. The problem is that when I TEST my procedure with input parameters `customer_num=1 / Order_by=2` the final result `is not sorted` on the second column and it is like this:

```
  Customer_Num       Channel_Code
  =============     ==============
       1                 5
       1                 4
       1                 6
```

But when I write a query with order by, it gives me the output below:

```
select *
from CUST_MODERN_CHANNEL_BRANCH t
where t.customer_num = 1
order by 2

  Customer_Num       Channel_Code
  =============     ==============
       1                 4
       1                 5
       1                 6
```

Is that something wrong with my procedure? Or the way I used bind variables?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order by 2` does not equal to `order by :ord` where `:ord = 2`.

With `order by 2`, `2` represents a position, meaning the result must be sorted always by 2nd column in `select` list.

With `order by :ord`, `:ord` is an expression, which will be evaluated to a value, and sorting will be done by that value, not a column.

If you use `order by :ord` where `:ord = 2`, that is handled like like `order by '2'` (logically, ignore the type difference for now).

Do not bind the order by position.

Comment: Thanks for you answer . My question is that why "order by :ord" is handled like order by '2' ? I mean WHY exactly does Oracle engine do that?? Why does not it understand that it should be treated like custumer_num=:cust ?

Comment: Because you can provide a variety of valid values for `:ord` and they may affect the optimizer to produce different execution plans based on the column used for sorting and it was not prepared for this case, not even in 19c.